# Try to do a function who swap element of a list

Tags: c

I would like to make this funtion with a simple pointer but it doesn't work!
The goal of this function is to put the first element to the end of a list.
Ex : a b c d e

```
                                            b c d e a
```

```
typedef struct liste liste_t;
struct liste
{
    int nbr;
    liste_t *next;
};
```

```
void put_at_the_end(liste_t *list)
{
    liste_t *temp1 = list;
    liste_t *temp2 = NULL;

    if (list == NULL || list->next == NULL)
        return (list);
    while (list->next->next != NULL)
        list = list->next;
    temp2 = list->next;
    temp2->next = temp1->next;
    temp1->next = NULL;
    list->next = temp1;
}
```

thanks for your help !

Comment: You need to be able to change the `list` pointer. But that is not possible with the current function prototype. Need to pass in a `liste_t **`

Comment: You cannot do this without changing the head of the list. Usually you do this by returning the (possibly) new head, or by passing a pointer to the pointer to the head. Even better you pass a pointer to a list object which contains a pointer to the head. Your `liste_t` type is in fact a `node_t`. Your function must chose: or it's void or it returns something.

Comment: avoid `**` when not needed. `**` is a side effect. Use return values instead. side effects should be avoided if not absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct list_t
{
    int nbr;
    struct list_t *next;
}list_t;

list_t *addEnd(list_t *head, const int nbr)
{
    list_t *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));

    if(node)
    {
        node -> next = NULL;
        node -> nbr = nbr;
        if(!head) head = node;
        else
        {
            list_t *current = head;
            while(current -> next) current = current -> next;
            current -> next = node;
        }
    }
    else head = NULL;
    return head;
}

list_t *addFront(list_t *head, const int nbr)
{
    list_t *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));

    if(node)
    {
        node -> next = head;
        node -> nbr = nbr;
        head = node;
    }
    else head = NULL;
    return head;
}

list_t *addMiddle(list_t *after, const int nbr)
{
    list_t *node = NULL;

    if(after)
    {
        node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
        if(node)
        {
            node -> next = after -> next;
            after -> next = node;
            node -> nbr = nbr;
        }
    }
    return node;
}

void printList(const list_t *head)
{
    size_t count = 0;
    while(head)
    {
        printf("Node [%2zu] NBR=%03d\n", ++count, head -> nbr);
        head = head -> next;
    }
    printf("Total number of nodes: %zu\n List end------------------\n", count);
}


int main(void)
{
    list_t *head = NULL, *tmp, *some;   

    for(int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if((tmp = addEnd(head, i))) head = tmp;
        printList(head);
    }

    if((some = addEnd(head, 5))) head = some;
    printList(head);

    for(int i = 10; i < 15; i++)
    {
        if((tmp = addFront(head, i))) head = tmp;
        printList(head);
    }

    for(int i = 100; i < 105; i++)
    {
        if(!addMiddle(some, i)) printf("Error\n");
        printList(head);
    }
    /* free memory */
}
```

```
Node [ 1] NBR=001
Total number of nodes: 1
 List end------------------
Node [ 1] NBR=001
Node [ 2] NBR=002
Total number of nodes: 2
 List end------------------
Node [ 1] NBR=001
Node [ 2] NBR=002
Node [ 3] NBR=003
Total number of nodes: 3
 List end------------------
Node [ 1] NBR=001
Node [ 2] NBR=002
Node [ 3] NBR=003
Node [ 4] NBR=005
Total number of nodes: 4
 List end------------------
Node [ 1] NBR=010
Node [ 2] NBR=001
Node [ 3] NBR=002
Node [ 4] NBR=003
Node [ 5] NBR=005
Total number of nodes: 5
 List end------------------
Node [ 1] NBR=011
Node [ 2] NBR=010
Node [ 3] NBR=001
Node [ 4] NBR=002
Node [ 5] NBR=003
Node [ 6] NBR=005
Total number of nodes: 6
 List end------------------
Node [ 1] NBR=012
Node [ 2] NBR=011
Node [ 3] NBR=010
Node [ 4] NBR=001
Node [ 5] NBR=002
Node [ 6] NBR=003
Node [ 7] NBR=005
Total number of nodes: 7
 List end------------------
Node [ 1] NBR=013
Node [ 2] NBR=012
Node [ 3] NBR=011
Node [ 4] NBR=010
Node [ 5] NBR=001
Node [ 6] NBR=002
Node [ 7] NBR=003
Node [ 8] NBR=005
Total number of nodes: 8
 List end------------------
Node [ 1] NBR=014
Node [ 2] NBR=013
Node [ 3] NBR=012
Node [ 4] NBR=011
Node [ 5] NBR=010
Node [ 6] NBR=001
Node [ 7] NBR=002
Node [ 8] NBR=003
Node [ 9] NBR=005
Total number of nodes: 9
 List end------------------
Node [ 1] NBR=014
Node [ 2] NBR=013
Node [ 3] NBR=012
Node [ 4] NBR=011
Node [ 5] NBR=010
Node [ 6] NBR=001
Node [ 7] NBR=100
Node [ 8] NBR=002
Node [ 9] NBR=003
Node [10] NBR=005
Total number of nodes: 10
 List end------------------
Node [ 1] NBR=014
Node [ 2] NBR=013
Node [ 3] NBR=012
Node [ 4] NBR=011
Node [ 5] NBR=010
Node [ 6] NBR=001
Node [ 7] NBR=101
Node [ 8] NBR=100
Node [ 9] NBR=002
Node [10] NBR=003
Node [11] NBR=005
Total number of nodes: 11
 List end------------------
Node [ 1] NBR=014
Node [ 2] NBR=013
Node [ 3] NBR=012
Node [ 4] NBR=011
Node [ 5] NBR=010
Node [ 6] NBR=001
Node [ 7] NBR=102
Node [ 8] NBR=101
Node [ 9] NBR=100
Node [10] NBR=002
Node [11] NBR=003
Node [12] NBR=005
Total number of nodes: 12
 List end------------------
Node [ 1] NBR=014
Node [ 2] NBR=013
Node [ 3] NBR=012
Node [ 4] NBR=011
Node [ 5] NBR=010
Node [ 6] NBR=001
Node [ 7] NBR=103
Node [ 8] NBR=102
Node [ 9] NBR=101
Node [10] NBR=100
Node [11] NBR=002
Node [12] NBR=003
Node [13] NBR=005
Total number of nodes: 13
 List end------------------
Node [ 1] NBR=014
Node [ 2] NBR=013
Node [ 3] NBR=012
Node [ 4] NBR=011
Node [ 5] NBR=010
Node [ 6] NBR=001
Node [ 7] NBR=104
Node [ 8] NBR=103
Node [ 9] NBR=102
Node [10] NBR=101
Node [11] NBR=100
Node [12] NBR=002
Node [13] NBR=003
Node [14] NBR=005
Total number of nodes: 14
 List end------------------
```